# using mod_rewrite while keeping relative links intact

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to implement clean urls on a website I'm developing.

I'm using .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When the user goes to `www.site.com/catalogue`, apache is sending them to: `www.site.com/index.php?page=catalogue`. and that's ok.

But if the user goes to `www.site.com/catalogue/item`, the site loses the relative links (css, javascript, images).

If the css file is located in css/site.css, apache thinks the html is asking for `catalogue/css/site.css`.

So: how do I keep the relative links intact while using mod_rewrite?

Also, I would like the solution to be adaptive enough to be able to work inside a folder, ex: `www.domain.com/folder/catalogue/item` and still refer to `www.domain.com/folder/index.php?page=catalogue`.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy workaround:

Use absolute path for resource files such as *.css, *.js, *.png, *.gif, *.jpg. ie,

You revise your HTML code from (BAD):

```
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalogue/css/site.css" />
```

=> GOOD:

```
 <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/catalogue/css/site.css" />
```

This requires your re-programming of PHP scripts.

Comment: Thank You, I'm using a php config file with: define('URL', '/folder/') , and <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo URL; ?>catalogue/css/site.css" /> for more flexibility.